# ActiveAdmin doesn't upload image when using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, activeadmin

I've followed all guides and answers, and everything displays correctly, but the actual upload doesn't happen :(

**Here's in my ActiveAdmin:**

```
form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :name
    f.input :image, :multipart => true
  end
end
```

**Here's in my model:**

```
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :path => ":rails_root/app/assets/images/article_images/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
```

I've tried without a path also, didn't work.

**Here's my migration:**

```
class AddAttachmentImageToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :articles, :image_file_name, :string
    add_column :articles, :image_content_type, :string
    add_column :articles, :image_file_size, :integer
    add_column :articles, :image_updated_at, :datetime
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :articles, :image_file_name
    remove_column :articles, :image_content_type
    remove_column :articles, :image_file_size
    remove_column :articles, :image_updated_at
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the damn attr_accessible not having :image

Answer (score 0):

Just for complete your answer it's necessary do somethings to work.

Add the gems:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'fog'
```

Add the configuration of config/application.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {:storage => :fog, 
                             :fog_credentials => {:provider => "Local", 
                                                  :local_root => "#{Rails.root}/public"}, 
                             :fog_directory => "", 
                             :fog_host => "http://localhost:3000"}
```

And to show the images at index just added this code:

```
index do
  column "Image" do |epc|
    link_to(image_tag(epc.imagem.url(:thumb), :height => '100'), admin_epc_path(epc))
  end
  default_actions
end
```